# How to check beacon's signal strength - nRF52832?

Tags: c, bluetooth-low-energy

I want to check beacon's RSSI using my nRF52832 (PCA10040) and if the signal is strong then send beacon's MAC over UART to WiFi module.

I'm having hard time understanding Nordic Semiconductor's documentation. I found `sd_ble_gap_scan_start` function but can't find any example code on how to use it.

```
m_scan_param.active       = 0;            // Active scanning set.
m_scan_param.selective    = 0;            // Selective scanning not set.
m_scan_param.interval     = 0x00A0;     // Scan interval.
m_scan_param.window       = 0x00A0;   // Scan window.
m_scan_param.p_whitelist  = NULL;         // No whitelist provided.
m_scan_param.timeout      = 0x0000;       // No timeout.

err_code = sd_ble_gap_scan_start(&m_scan_param);
APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
```

I'm using Keil uVision.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following post on the Nordic's website.
https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/59623/rssi-without-connection/

It was an answer to your same question on Nordic's forums.

Re-posted here for other readers of electronics stack exchange.